# conputer vision with go get me an error when i try to download it

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, go

whem i use the comand:

$ go get -u -d gocv.io/x/gocv

i get the error:

package gocv.io/x/gocv: cannot download, /home/ariel/go is a GOROOT, not a GOPATH. For more details see: 'go help gopath'

iḿ using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What is your output from the command `go env`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have installed the go binary into where your default GOPATH is. Either set the GOPATH to be something different, or move your installation.